# Matlab Gradient Over set of data

Tags: matlab, gradient, noise

I have a set of data which has a long baseline, with noise fluctuating around 0 then a point where an exponential curve occurs.

[image]

I'm looking for some relatively simple code that finds the point where the exponential curve begins. I need it to do it automatically because it for 1000's of different curves. So I can't just find the value myself from the plot.

I have a model for what the fit should be after the 'zero point'

How could I do this, in a relatively simple operation?

Currently my code finds an average of the baseline noise and then says when it goes above this point, the curve has begun. However, this isn't accurate enough.

Comment: There is not enough information to answer this question.

Comment: You, indeed, did not give us enough to go off of; however, you did say it's a log plot.  You can go up to where the log curve is strong and back-calculate the log via something like polyfit(x[20:100], log(y(20:100)), 1);

Comment: What other information would you like?

Comment: I've added an image of an example plot. The red circle is where my code currently thinks the 'zero point' is.

Answer (score 0):

You could take all the data points that have y value larger than 10% of the maximal y value and fit them to an exponential function y=exp((x-a)/b). Take natural log of you data points y(i) and fit these data points to ln(y)=(x-a)/b and I would take a/b as the "zero point". Hope this helps but if you can upload part of the data I can write a simple code to test my proposed solution.